# cumsum starting over after NA

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. For one column I would like to calculate the cumulative sums but I have some trouble with missing values.

```
#sample data
test <- c(-1.2, 4.6, -8.3, 5, 8, 1, -2, NA, NA, NA, -3, 5.1, 1.9)
test <- as.data.frame(test)

#This gives NA after NAs occurred
sum_test <- lapply(test, FUN=cumsum)

sum_test
$test
 [1] -1.2  3.4 -4.9  0.1  8.1  9.1  7.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

#This continues with adding to pre-NA value after last NA
sum_test <- lapply(test, function(x) ave(x, is.na(x), FUN=cumsum))

sum_test
$test
 [1] -1.2  3.4 -4.9  0.1  8.1  9.1  7.1   NA   NA   NA  4.1  9.2 11.1
```

However, what I would like to achieve is that after the NAs cumsum starts over:

```
-1.2  3.4 -4.9  0.1  8.1  9.1  7.1   NA   NA   NA -3   2.1   4
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
test <- c(-1.2, 4.6, -8.3, 5, 8, 1, -2, NA, NA, NA, -3, 5.1, 1.9)
tmp <- rle(is.na(test))
ind <- rep(seq_along(tmp$value), tmp$lengths)
as.vector(unlist(tapply(test, ind, cumsum)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Here `g` defines a grouping variable and then we apply `cumsum` separately over each group:

```
test <- c(-1.2, 4.6, -8.3, 5, 8, 1, -2, NA, NA, NA, -3, 5.1, 1.9)
g <- cumsum(is.na(head(c(0, test), -1)))
ave(test, g, FUN = cumsum)
```

which gives:

```
[1] -1.2  3.4 -4.9  0.1  8.1  9.1  7.1   NA   NA   NA -3.0  2.1  4.0
```

*ADDED:*  Note that `head(c(0, test), -1)` just lags `test` so dplyr's `lag` function could be used to shorten this slightly:

```
library(dplyr)
ave(test, cumsum(is.na(lag(test))), FUN = cumsum)
```

Comment: This is great.  Could `na.omit` be used for the same problem?

Comment: `na.omit` outputs a vector which is typically shorter than its input so it seems unlikely to be useful here.